# I have created virtualhost using nginx but getting 403 Forbidden

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, ubuntu-22.04

I have set up a virtual host using nginx, but I am encountering a 403 Forbidden. This issue only occurs in Ubuntu 22.04, whereas the same configuration works fine on Ubuntu 20.04.

I want to solve 403 Forbidden error for nginx virtual host

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the increased security in Ubuntu 22.04, many users are encountering the same issue. To resolve this, you need to add your user to the "www-data" group.

```
sudo usermod -g www-data <YOUR_USERNAME>

i.e sudo usermod -g www-data ubuntu
```